# Lemmatization Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, lemmatization

I am a beginner at Pandas and I am trying to figure out how to lemmatize a single column of my dataframe. Take the following example (this is some text after (un)common word removal which I'd like to lemmatize):

> 0    good needs changes virgils natural micro brewe...
>
> 1    new favorite given delightful surprise find fl...
>
> 2    red sauce favorite enjoy strong tannin ok pull...
>
> 3    quality fantastic 1800s 21st century try drink...
>
> 4    red first time trying love 100excellent blend ...

This is the code I use to do lemmatization (taken from [here](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/02/the-different-methods-deal-text-data-predictive-python/)):

```
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(lambda x: "".join([Word(word).lemmatize() for word in x]))
df['words'].head()
```

But once this code is run the output doesn't change:

> 0    good need change virgil natural micro brewed r...
>
> 1    new favorite given delightful surprise find fl...
>
> 2    red sauce favorite enjoy strong tannin ok pull...
>
> 3    quality fantastic 1800s 21st century try drink...
>
> 4    red first time trying love 100excellent blend ...

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

P.S: `words` is a list of tokenized words

Comment: It looks like `needs` => `need`, `changes` => `change`, and `virgils` => `virgil` so the output does change.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Oh, yeah... I was more focusing on `trying` shouldn't it become `try`? Or `brewed` should become `brew`

Comment: Fair point. In that case, your problem may be more complicated than it is, because you'd have to specify the parts of speech (POS) for the verbs that you just alluded to. If you run the `lemmatize` method without specifying the POS, it will fail. Therefore, in the case of `trying` and `brewed` the code would have to be `Word('trying').lemmatize('v')` and `Word('brewed').lemmatize('v')`. [Source](http://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/quickstart.html#words-inflection-and-lemmatization)

Answer (score 2):

You probably don't need anymore solution, but if you want to lemmatize on many pos, you can use:

If you want more, you can try the following code:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
lemmatizer = nltk.stem.WordNetLemmatizer()
wordnet_lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
stop = stopwords.words('english')


def nltk_tag_to_wordnet_tag(nltk_tag):
    if nltk_tag.startswith('J'):
        return wordnet.ADJ
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('V'):
        return wordnet.VERB
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('N'):
        return wordnet.NOUN
    elif nltk_tag.startswith('R'):
        return wordnet.ADV
    else:
        return None

def lemmatize_sentence(sentence):
    #tokenize the sentence and find the POS tag for each token
    nltk_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(nltk.word_tokenize(sentence))
    #tuple of (token, wordnet_tag)
    wordnet_tagged = map(lambda x: (x[0], nltk_tag_to_wordnet_tag(x[1])), nltk_tagged)
    lemmatized_sentence = []
    for word, tag in wordnet_tagged:
        if tag is None:
            #if there is no available tag, append the token as is
            lemmatized_sentence.append(word)
        else:
            #else use the tag to lemmatize the token
            lemmatized_sentence.append(lemmatizer.lemmatize(word, tag))
    return " ".join(lemmatized_sentence)



# Lemmatizing
df['Lemmatize'] = df['word'].apply(lambda x: lemmatize_sentence(x))
print(df.head())
```

df result:

```
         word                       |        Lemmatize

0  Best scores, good cats, it rocks | Best score , good cat , it rock

1          You received best scores |          You receive best score

2                         Good news |                       Good news

3                          Bad news |                        Bad news

4                    I am loving it |                    I be love it

5                    it rocks a lot |                   it rock a lot

6     it is still good to do better |     it be still good to do good
```